# Money withdrawn from ATM was stolen from tray when momentarily distracted

Tags: atm

I had $160 stolen from me after withdrawing it at an ATM with my PayPal card (which is linked to my Wells Fargo checking account). I was momentarily distracted and the funds were swiped from the tray in just a few seconds. Is it possible to get my funds replaced by either PayPal or my bank?

Comment: It seems unlikely since, from your description of the event, neither of them were at fault. Is there anything which makes you believe they should reimburse you for your loss?

Comment: The bank might be able help with a police investigation if they have video surveillance. Try contacting the police and the bank.

Answer (score 10):

You should report the theft to the police. That is what it is. The police may also want to contact the ATM owner to get access to any security footage.

The ATM owner would only have responsibility if they provided substandard security. But based on all the locations I have seen ATMs I don't expect that there is any standard for security.

If as part of the incident the card was also stolen, then report that to the card issuer.

Depending on where you are it might be a loss you can deduct from your taxes, but the amount is probably too low. There is also the possibility of an insurance claim, but it would depend on the policy you have and any deductible that policy has. If you are going the tax or insurance route you should also get a copy of the police report for proof.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My wife and I decided that the chance of getting the money returned is just too remote to justify the time and energy required in order to pursue any sort of legal action. We're chalking it up to an expensive learning experience and investing more time and headspace into it would drive up the impact of what amounts to a stupid mistake on my part as much as an act of dispicable, underhanded skullduggery on the part of the perpetrator. Many thanks to those who left suggestions, tho. You've made an investment of kindnesses without the expectation of a return on it. 